# Xmonad build failed: cound not find module control.monad.reader

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, xmonad, cabal-install

I'm trying to cabal install xmonad with profiling and I keep getting the error: cound not find module control.monad.reader

The error message suggested that I may not have installed the profiling libs for mtl-2.0.1.0, but I have confirmed that it is installed with ghc-pkg list | grep mtl. I then took a stab at running ghc-pkg expose on it, but no luck.

I tried googling and checking SO, but all I could find were problems related to having multiple instances of control.monad.reader installed and ghc being unable to determine which to use.

Right now, I'm just out of ideas about what do, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have `mtl` installed does NOT mean you have the profiling libraries installed.  You shouldn't need profiling - how are you installing XMonad?  Did you change your cabal config file recently to enable profiling?

The way I see it you can either reinstall `mtl` with profiling:

```
cabal install --reinstall --enable-library-profiling mtl
```

Then install XMonad, or just disable profiling for the xmonad installation:

```
cabal install --disable-library-profiling xmonad
```

(I'm assuming that will override the setting from the config file)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Thomas M. DuBuisson. By following your advice I discovered that transformers was also installed without profiling. Once I reintalled that, then mtl, I was able to successfully install xmonad with profiling.